# Installed packages are not find by the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I've installed [formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik) and [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) using `npm install formik` and `npm install yup`.

They appear in package.json in dependencies object.

In my file they are imported like:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
```

but when I run `npm start` I get this error message:

> ```
> Line 3:22:  Unable to resolve path to module 'yup'     import/no-unresolved
> Line 5:37:  Unable to resolve path to module 'formik'  import/no-unresolved
> ```

What is the reason of this? Maybe it is something related to eslint.

My eslintrc:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "react-app",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/flowtype",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    // Allow jsx tags inside .js files.
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, {"extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]}],
    // Disable props spreading (<App {...props} />) warning.
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 1,
    // Throw warning instead of error when using array index as a key.
    "react/no-array-index-key": 1,
    // Disable react prop-types validation
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    // Allow modules with named exports only.
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    // Throw warning instead of error. Feel free to choose your favorite option https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style
    "arrow-body-style": ["warn", "as-needed"],
    // Make prettier code formatting suggestions more verbose.
    "prettier/prettier": ["warn"],
    // Throw warning when <a href="#"> or <a href="javascript:void(0)"> are used. Use <button> instead.
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": ["warn", {"aspects": ["invalidHref"]}],
    // Allow using (props) => <Component /> and ({propName}) => <Component /> syntax.
    "react/destructuring-assignment": "off",
    // Disable <Fragment> => <> replacement. Feel free to change
    "react/jsx-fragments": "off",
    // Below is the set of functional rules to warn developer about accidental mutations, which may cause error in reducers etc.
    // No delete operator.
    "fp/no-delete": "warn",
    // Warning when Object.assign(a, b) used, since it mutates first argument. Object.assign({}, a, b) is ok.
    "fp/no-mutating-assign": "warn",
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": true}]
  },
  "plugins": ["prettier", "fp"],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "./src"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My package-json:

```json
{
  "name": "graab-bo-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-fp": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "react-semantic-ui-datepickers": "^2.7.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reduxsauce": "^1.1.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "fix": "eslint --fix ./src/",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^2.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.18"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you cheked these packages are correctly installed or not ?

Comment: how can I check it? I assume that if they appear in package.json they are installed correctly

Answer (score 0):

See `ls node_modules/{yup,formik}` if packages are correctly in place.

If so, just try restarting the react server. 
If not, reinstall with `npm install` (if it's already in `package.json`).

Comment: tried it, still doesn't work. I updated my question with package.json and eslintrc files, maybe it's something related to them